# How to obtain specific key values from a JSON response with list of objects and perform arithmetic operation from extracted values

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I have written code to get data from an AWS API. I was able to parse the JSON data from the API. I'm filtering out only the running instances through the API and extract its data. The output is a JSON response.

Im trying to :

1. retrieve `corecount` and `ThreadsPerCore` values of the running instances,
2. later i will have to multiply `corecount`x `ThreadsPerCore` = `vcpus` of the respective instances.
3. and summing up all `vcpus` of the running instances.

How can I write code that does this ?

I read some tutorials, so I understand that I need to use [] to access elements of the nested lists and dictionaries; and I tried retrieving values using it for a single set of data (only for INSTANCE-1) but I can't figure out exactly how it works in my case where I may have 'n' of set of datas ( INSTANCE 1, 2, 3, .....) with specific values needs to be obtained. Hence here I have implemented `for loop` and again the work gets complex when i had to do the arithmetic operations.

here is the JSON output structure which contains 3 sets of data (for 3 running instances) in this example but might differ based on scenarios:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                "ImageId": "ami-123",
                "InstanceId": "INSTANCE-1",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",
                "State": {
                    "Code": 16,
                    "Name": "running"
                },
                "StateTransitionReason": "",
                "CpuOptions": {
                    "CoreCount": 4,
                    "ThreadsPerCore": 2
                },
     ],
        "OwnerId": "123456789012"
        "ReservationId": "r-02a3f596d91211712",
    },
    {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                "ImageId": "ami-123",
                "InstanceId": "INSATNCE-2",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",
                "State": {
                    "Code": 16,
                    "Name": "running"
                },
                "StateTransitionReason": "",
                "CpuOptions": {
                    "CoreCount": 8,
                    "ThreadsPerCore": 2
                },
     ],
        "OwnerId": "123456789012"
        "ReservationId": "r-02a3f596d91211712",
    },
    {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                "ImageId": "ami-123",
                "InstanceId": "INSTANCE-3",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",
                "State": {
                    "Code": 16,
                    "Name": "running"
                },
                "StateTransitionReason": "",
                "CpuOptions": {
                    "CoreCount": 4,
                    "ThreadsPerCore": 2
                },
     ],
        "OwnerId": "123456789012"
        "ReservationId": "r-02a3f596d91211712",
    }
  ]
}
```

My code to retrieve `CpuOptions` :  `CoreCount` and `ThreadsPerCore` values is :

```
from shell import run_command_str
import json
cmd = "aws ec2 describe-instances  --output json --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"
output = run_command_str(command=cmd, shell_command=True)
status = json.loads(output)

corecount = {}
for reservation in status1["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        corecount[instance["InstanceId"]] = instance["CpuOptions"]["CoreCount"]
print(corecount)

threadspercore = {}

for reservation in status1["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        threadspercore[instance["InstanceId"]] = instance["CpuOptions"]["ThreadsPerCore"]
print(threadspercore)
```

The output for this code:

```
{'INSTANCE-1': 4, 'INSTANCE-2': 8, 'INSTANCE-3': 4}  ###corecount values
{'INSTANCE-1': 2, 'INSTANCE-2': 2, 'INSTANCE-3': 2}   ###Threadpercore values
```

Comment: Hello. The JSON output you posted in your question has invalid formatting. Use an online JSON formatter to format your JSON and then post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to compute `vcpus` and sum of all `vcpus` from `corecount` and `threadspercore`:

```py
corecount = {"INSTANCE-1": 4, "INSTANCE-2": 8, "INSTANCE-3": 4}
threadspercore = {"INSTANCE-1": 2, "INSTANCE-2": 2, "INSTANCE-3": 2}

vcpus = {k: corecount[k] * threadspercore[k] for k in corecount}
sum_vcpus = sum(vcpus.values())

print(corecount)
print(threadspercore)
print(vcpus)
print(sum_vcpus)
```

Prints:

```py
{'INSTANCE-1': 4, 'INSTANCE-2': 8, 'INSTANCE-3': 4}
{'INSTANCE-1': 2, 'INSTANCE-2': 2, 'INSTANCE-3': 2}
{'INSTANCE-1': 8, 'INSTANCE-2': 16, 'INSTANCE-3': 8}
32
```